# Infinite loop when for loop is abstracted as Macro in C

Tags: c, loops, macros, infinite

i am scratching my head over this, i wonder why it is going in infinite loop. Appreciate help. With one loop it works fine, but with nested loop it is going inside infinite loop. Can anyone pls clarify what is the problem here ?

```
typedef enum nh_type{
IPNH,
LSPNH,
NH_MAX
} nh_type_t;

#define ITERATE_NH_TYPE_BEGIN(_nh)     \
    for(_nh = IPNH; _nh < NH_MAX; nh++)

#define ITERATE_NH_TYPE_END


int main(void)
{
nh_type_t nh, nh1;
ITERATE_NH_TYPE_BEGIN(nh){
    ITERATE_NH_TYPE_BEGIN(nh1){
            printf("nh = %s, nh1 = %s\n",
            nh == IPNH ? "IPNH" : "LSPNH",
            nh1 == IPNH ? "IPNH" : "LSPNH");
    }ITERATE_NH_TYPE_END
} ITERATE_NH_TYPE_END
return 0;
}
```

**output**

```
vm@vm:~$ ./a.out
nh = IPNH, nh1 = IPNH
nh = LSPNH, nh1 = IPNH
nh = LSPNH, nh1 = IPNH
nh = LSPNH, nh1 = IPNH
nh = LSPNH, nh1 = IPNH
nh = LSPNH, nh1 = IPNH
nh = LSPNH, nh1 = IPNH .... infinite loop
```

Comment: You mistyped `_nh` as `nh`.

Comment: The urge to write macros like this is, unfortunately, a disease which strikes many beginning C programmers.  Get well soon.

Comment: The classical example of macro abuse. Unreadable, undeboggable and pointless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch your #define macro:

```
#define ITERATE_NH_TYPE_BEGIN(_nh) \
for(_nh = IPNH; _nh < NH_MAX; nh++)
```

Should be:

```
#define ITERATE_NH_TYPE_BEGIN(_nh) \
for(_nh = IPNH; _nh < NH_MAX; _nh++)
```